# Control-Click hyperlink to open in libreoffice-calc

Tags: hyperlink, libreoffice-calc

When using the libreoffice spreadsheet program 'calc', clicking on a cell containing a hyperlink will immediately open it in a web browser. I would prefer to control-click it to open that link in a web browser. How can I do this?

There looks like such an option in the security settings, but it seems not to do anything.

Comment: I've added a RfE - see the link in my reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option in the security settings affects only the Writer component. I think it would be useful to have this option for Calc and Impress documents, too.

**EDIT:** Here's my [request for enhancement (libreoffice bugzilla entry)](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51296) regarding this issue.